# Gnuplot: how to plot 3d image using vertex data?

Tags: stl, gnuplot

I'm new to Gnuplot.
I want to draw a 3d image by vertex data.
how do I plot this data file correctly?

thank you for reading

---datafile format is like this---

x     y       z

0.0   2.1     4

0.5   0.4     1.2

0.2   0.3     0.3

0.6   0.4     0.9

0.3   0.6     0.2

0.4   3.2     1.6

.

.

.

Comment: This data format is from an STL file. I must use an STL data for calculating some physical quantity. This x,y,z data is vertices.

Comment: What kind of image do you expect? Can you link to a similar one?

Comment: https://nasa3d.arc.nasa.gov/detail/bennu   this is the same file type.                               I will use these vertex. I wouldn't use normals

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in the file `vertex.dat`, you can do

```
splot 'vertex.dat' using 1:2:3 with lines
```

to draw a line between consecutive points. The output is something like this:

[image]